# What happens to stack variables if they are reassigned by malloc?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm trying to understand what happens when stack/heap variables are mixed in C, for example:

```
typedef struct E...

void foo(E* param) {
    param = malloc(sizeof(E));
}

int main() {
    E myParam;
    foo(&myParam);
    free(&myParam); //???
}
```

If we run main(), some struct myParam is declared on main's stack frame.  But then foo() re-points param to a malloc'd block of heap memory.  What happens to the stack memory that was allocated to myParam?  Is it "wasted" and won't change even if we set fields in myParam?  And can we still free the malloc'd memory as in the code above?

Comment: `foo()` setting of `param` does not affect `myParam`. `param` is originally a copy of the address of `myParam`. `free(&myParam)` is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens to the stack memory that was allocated to myParam?

Nothing.

> Is it "wasted" and won't change even if we set fields in myParam?

No, it is not wasted. It will change if you set fields in `myParam`.

> And can we still free the malloc'd memory as in the code above?

No, you can't. The memory allocated in `foo` gets assigned to a local variable. It is a memory leak. Calling

```
free(&myParam);
```

leads to undefined behavior. `&myParam` was not allocated using `malloc` (or its family of functions). That is cause for undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand what happens when stack/heap variables are
>   mixed in C, for example:

Nothing consistent, repeatable or useful. The essence of Undefined Behavior. It will differ based on

1. Each compiler
2. Each implementation of stdlib (malloc heap manager)
3. Each program and iteration

One implementation of malloc/free might be a smart heap that checks the validity of addresses you pass to free() to verify that they are in valid "arenas" or heap regions, before carrying out any action. The next malloc implementation might make an assumption that the pointer you passed to free was correct, and access or set hidden heap bookkeeping values in an address relative to the pointer you passed. Since the pointer is incorrect, you are essentially writing all over your program stack and potentially hosing the heap organization at the same time.

There is no standard implementation of malloc/free so there are a bunch of possibilities.

A stack address is just a garbage value as far as free() is concerned, and if free() assumes the address is within a heap region that has been divided up by the buddy system, it will treat your stack like its heap regions, not something good, nor anything that will make any sense, from an experiment standpoint.

No different from passing an invalid pointer to a call to "fread()" or "memcpy()"